# Problem in understanding Python list comprehensions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

What does the last line mean in the following code?

```
import pickle, urllib                                                                                                                                                     

  handle = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p")
  data = pickle.load(handle)
  handle.close()

  for elt in data:
         print "".join([e[1] * e[0] for e in elt])
```

My attempt to the problem:

- "".join... uses join -method to empty text
- e[1] * e[0] multiplies two subsequent values in the sequence, e
- I am not sure what is e
- I am not sure, what it means, when you have something before for -loop, like: `e[1] * e[0] for e in elt`

Comment: I really enjoyed the python challenge back when I took it a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe best explained with an example:

```
print "".join([e[1] * e[0] for e in elt])
```

is the short form of

```
x = []
for e in elt:
  x.append(e[1] * e[0])
print "".join(x)
```

List comprehensions are simply syntactic sugar for `for` loops, which make an expression out of a sequence of statements.

`elt` can be an arbitrary object, since you load it from pickles, and `e` likewise. The usage suggests that is it a [sequence](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) type, but it could just be anything that implements the sequence protocol.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you need to put http:// in front of the URL, ie:

```
handle = urllib.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p")
```

An expression `[e for e in a_list]` is a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) which generates a list of values.

With Python strings, the `*` operator is used to repeat a string. Try typing in the commands one by one into an interpreter then look at data:

```
>>> data[0]
[(' ', 95)]
```

This shows us each line of data is a tuple containing two elements.

Thus the expression `e[1] * e[0]` is effectively the string in `e[0]` repeated `e[1]` times.

Hence the program draws a banner.

Comment: But switch the elements: e[0] = 95 and e[1] = ' '.

Comment: thanks for the correction - I am so used to doing the "sensible" thing of multiplying a string by an integer that I read it as being that way around, especially as that's how the data is stored!

Answer (score 4):

`[e[1] * e[0] for e in elt]` is a list comprehension, which evaluates to a list itself by looping through another list, in this case `elt`.  Each element in the new list is `e[1]*e[0]`, where `e` is the corresponding element in `elt`.

Comment: e may be anything that implements __getitem__.

Comment: That's true, I made a bad assumption.

Answer (score 2):

The question itself has already been fully answered but I'd like to add that a list comprehension also supports filtering.  Your original line

```
print "".join([e[1] * e[0] for e in elt])
```

could,  as an example,  become

```
print "".join([e[1] * e[0] for e in elt if len(e) == 2])
```

to only operate on items in elt that have two elements.

Answer (score 1):

join() is a string method, that works on a separator in new string

```
>>> ':'.join(['ab', 'cd'])
>>> 'ab:cd'
```

and list comprehension is not necessary there, generator would suffice

Answer (score 1):

Andy's is a great answer!

If you want to see every step of the loop (with line-breaks) try this out:

```
for elt in data:
    for e in elt:
        print "e[0] == %s, e[1] == %d, which gives us:  '%s'" % (e[0], e[1], ''.join(e[1] * e[0]))
```

Comment: It gives a long list of: e[0] == %s, e[1] == %d

Comment: @Masi:  Thanks for noticing that.  
Maybe the line-break character ("\") was causing problems.  
I have removed it from the response.