# How to split by comma and strip white spaces in Python?

Tags: python, list, split, whitespace, strip

I have some python code that splits on comma, but doesn't strip the whitespace:

```
>>> string = "blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here "
>>> mylist = string.split(',')
>>> print mylist
['blah', ' lots  ', '  of ', '  spaces', ' here ']
```

I would rather end up with whitespace removed like this:

```
['blah', 'lots', 'of', 'spaces', 'here']
```

I am aware that I could loop through the list and strip() each item but, as this is Python, I'm guessing there's a quicker, easier and more elegant way of doing it.

Answer (score 815, accepted):

Use list comprehension -- simpler, and just as easy to read as a `for` loop.

```
my_string = "blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here "
result = [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')]
# result is ["blah", "lots", "of", "spaces", "here"]
```

**See:** [Python docs on List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)
[A good 2 second explanation of list comprehension.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501308/problem-in-understanding-python-list-comprehensions/501323#501323)

Comment: Super good!  I added one item as follows to get rid of the blank list entries.
> text = [x.strip() for x in text.split('.') if x != '']

Comment: @Sean: was invalid/incomplete python code your "original intent of the post"? According to the review wankers it was: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21504253. Can you please tell them otherwise by making the correction if they are wrong (again)?

Comment: The original was copy-pasted from a REPL (if I remember correctly) and the goal was understanding of the underlying concept (using list comprehension to perform an operation) - but you're right, it makes more sense if you *see* that list comprehension produces a new list.

Answer (score 49):

I came to add:

```
map(str.strip, string.split(','))
```

but saw it had already been mentioned by Jason Orendorff in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071396/4071416#comment4377858_4071416).

Reading Glenn Maynard's [comment on the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4071396/4071416#comment4375863_4071416) suggesting list comprehensions over map I started to wonder why. I assumed he meant for performance reasons, but of course he might have meant for stylistic reasons, or something else (Glenn?).

So a quick (possibly flawed?) test on my box (Python 2.6.5 on Ubuntu 10.04) applying the three methods in a loop revealed:

```sh
$ time ./list_comprehension.py  # [word.strip() for word in string.split(',')]
real    0m22.876s

$ time ./map_with_lambda.py     # map(lambda s: s.strip(), string.split(','))
real    0m25.736s

$ time ./map_with_str.strip.py  # map(str.strip, string.split(','))
real    0m19.428s
```

making `map(str.strip, string.split(','))` the winner, although it seems they are all in the same ballpark.

Certainly though map (with or without a lambda) should not necessarily be ruled out for performance reasons, and for me it is at least as clear as a list comprehension.

Comment: better answer `list(map(str.strip, string.split(',')))`

Comment: Cleanest and fastest

Answer (score 29):

Split using a regular expression. Note I made the case more general with leading spaces. The list comprehension is to remove the null strings at the front and back.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "  blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here "
>>> pattern = re.compile("^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$")
>>> print([x for x in pattern.split(string) if x])
['blah', 'lots', 'of', 'spaces', 'here']
```

This works even if `^\s+` doesn't match:

```
>>> string = "foo,   bar  "
>>> print([x for x in pattern.split(string) if x])
['foo', 'bar']
>>>
```

Here's why you need ^\s+:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile("\s*,\s*|\s+$")
>>> print([x for x in pattern.split(string) if x])
['  blah', 'lots', 'of', 'spaces', 'here']
```

See the leading spaces in blah?

*Clarification: above uses the Python 3 interpreter, but results are the same in Python 2.*

Comment: I believe `[x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')]` is more pythonic for the question asked. Maybe there are cases where my solution is necessary. I'll update this content if I run across one.

Comment: Why is `^\s+` necessary? I've tested your code without it and it doesn't work, but I don't know why.

Comment: If I use `re.compile("^\s*,\s*$")`, result is `['  blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here ']`.

Comment: @laike9m, I updated my answer to show you the difference. `^\s+` makes. As you can see for yourself, `^\s*,\s*$` doesn't return desired results, either. So if you want split with a regexp, use `^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$`.

Comment: The first match is empty if the leading pattern (^\s+) doesn't match so you get something like [ '', 'foo', 'bar' ] for the string "foo,  bar".

Comment: `re.split('\s*,\s*', "  blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here ".strip())` returns `['blah', 'lots', 'of', 'spaces', 'here']` and avoids the special cases in the regular expression.

Comment: I don't think replacing the special cases in the regexp with a call to a string method is a clear win.

Comment: `re.split(r"[^\w']+", input.strip())` for splitting on anything other than word characters and apostrophe. `re.split("[ ,]+", input.strip())` for splitting on just spaces and commas.  Both consume multiple 'split' characters so there are no empty strings in the output

Answer (score 23):

Just remove the white space from the string before you split it.

```
mylist = my_string.replace(' ','').split(',')
```

Comment: Kind of a problem if the items separated by commas contain embedded spaces, e.g. `"you just, broke this"`.

Comment: Geeze, a -1 for this. You guys are tough. It solved his problem, providing his sample data was only single words and there was no specification that the data would be phrases. But w/e, I guess thats how you guys roll around here.

Comment: Well thanks anyway, user. To be fair though I specifically asked for split and then strip() and strip removes leading and trailing whitespace and doesn't touch anything in between. A slight change and your answer would work perfectly, though: mylist = mystring.strip().split(',') although I don't know if this is particularly efficient.

Answer (score 14):

I know this has already been answered, but if you end doing this a lot, regular expressions may be a better way to go:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\s', '', string).split(',')
['blah', 'lots', 'of', 'spaces', 'here']
```

The `\s` matches any whitespace character, and we just replace it with an empty string `''`. You can find more info here: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: Your example would not work on strings containing spaces. "for, example this, one" would become "for", "examplethis", "one". Not saying it's a BAD solution (it works perfectly on my example) it just depends on the task in hand!

Comment: Yep, that's very correct!  You could probably adjust the regexp so it can handle strings with spaces, but if the list comprehension works, I'd say stick with it ;)

Answer (score 5):

`map(lambda s: s.strip(), mylist)` would be a little better than explicitly looping. Or for the whole thing at once: `map(lambda s:s.strip(), string.split(','))`

Comment: Tip: any time you find yourself using `map`, particularly if you're using `lambda` with it, double-check to see if you should be using a list comprehension.

Comment: You can avoid the lambda with `map(str.strip, s.split(','))`.

Answer (score 2):

`re` (as in regular expressions) allows splitting on multiple characters at once:

```
$ string = "blah, lots  ,  of ,  spaces, here "
$ re.split(', ',string)
['blah', 'lots  ', ' of ', ' spaces', 'here ']
```

This doesn't work well for your example string, but works nicely for a comma-space separated list. For your example string, you can combine the re.split power to split on *regex patterns* to get a "split-on-this-or-that" effect.

```
$ re.split('[, ]',string)
['blah',
 '',
 'lots',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'of',
 '',
 '',
 '',
 'spaces',
 '',
 'here',
 '']
```

Unfortunately, that's ugly, but a `filter` will do the trick:

```
$ filter(None, re.split('[, ]',string))
['blah', 'lots', 'of', 'spaces', 'here']
```

Voila!

Comment: Why not just `re.split(' *, *', string)`?

Comment: @PaulTomblin good idea. One can also have done this: `re.split('[, ]*',string)` for the same effect.

Comment: Dannid I realized after writing that that it doesn't strip whitespace at the beginning and the end like @tbc0's answer does.

Comment: @PaulTomblinheh, and my rebuttal `[, ]*` leaves an empty string at the end of the list. I think filter is still a nice thing to throw in there, or stick to list comprehension like the top answer does.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
result=[x for x in re.split(',| ',your_string) if x!='']
```

this works fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
mylist = [x for x in re.compile('\s*[,|\s+]\s*').split(string)]
```

Simply, comma or at least one white spaces with/without preceding/succeeding white spaces.

Please try!

Answer (score 1):

```
s = 'bla, buu, jii'

sp = []
sp = s.split(',')
for st in sp:
    print st
```