# How to split a string of space separated numbers into integers?

Tags: python, arrays, string, split, integer

I have a string `"42 0"` (for example) and need to get an array of the two integers. Can I do a `.split` on a space?

---

<sub>The obvious approach to this problem is a common combination of simple tasks:</sub>

- <sub>[How do I split a string into a list of words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743806)</sub>
- <sub>[How do I parse a string to a float or int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906)</sub>
- <sub>[How can I collect the results of a repeated calculation in a list, dictionary etc. (or make a copy of a list with each element modified)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75666408)</sub>

<sub>However, depending on the exact requirements, it can be addressed in other ways. For some cases, the split step may be sufficient on its own. There are other approaches, given in some answers here, to produce different output besides a native Python `list` - for example, using the standard library `array.array`, or a Numpy array.</sub>

<sub>Alternately, the problem can be seen as a special case of [How to extract numbers from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4289331) .</sub>

Comment: Somewhat related: [How to split by comma and strip white spaces in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071396)

Answer (score 148):

Use [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> "42 0".split()  # or .split(" ")
['42', '0']
```

Note that `str.split(" ")` is identical in this case, but would behave differently if there were more than one space in a row. As well, `.split()` splits on all whitespace, not just spaces.

Using `map` usually looks cleaner than using list comprehensions when you want to convert the items of iterables to built-ins like `int`, `float`, `str`, etc. In Python 2:

```
>>> map(int, "42 0".split())
[42, 0]
```

In Python 3, `map` will return a lazy object. You can get it into a list with `list()`:

```
>>> map(int, "42 0".split())
<map object at 0x7f92e07f8940>
>>> list(map(int, "42 0".split()))
[42, 0]
```

Answer (score 69):

```
text = "42 0"
nums = [int(n) for n in text.split()]
```

Comment: int(n) may raise a ValueError if it does not work by the way

Answer (score 13):

```
l = (int(x) for x in s.split())
```

If you are sure there are always two integers you could also do:

```
a,b = (int(x) for x in s.split())
```

or if you plan on modifying the array after

```
l = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
```

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
[ int(x) for x in "40 1".split(" ") ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course you can call `split`, but it will return strings, not integers. Do

```
>>> x, y = "42 0".split()
>>> [int(x), int(y)]
[42, 0]
```

or

```
[int(x) for x in "42 0".split()]
```

Answer (score 3):

Other answers already show that you can use [split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the values into a [list](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).  If you were asking about Python's [arrays](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), here is one solution:

```
import array
s = '42 0'
a = array.array('i')
for n in s.split():
    a.append(int(n))
```

Edit:  A more concise solution:

```
import array
s = '42 0'
a = array.array('i', (int(t) for t in s.split()))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can split and ensure the substring is a digit in a single line:

```
In [1]: [int(i) for i in '1 2 3a'.split() if i.isdigit()]
Out[1]: [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given: `text = "42 0"`

```
import re
numlist = re.findall('\d+',text)

print(numlist)

['42', '0']
```

Comment: This would, I assume, help with this specific example, but it would be good to see an answer re the ability to split on a space.

Comment: The question asks for a list of ***ints***, not ***strings***...

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy's [`fromstring`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html):

```
import numpy as np

np.fromstring("42 0", dtype=int, sep=' ')
```

```
>>> array([42,  0])
```