# In Python, how do I split a string to a number of integers? 

Tags: python, string, integer

This works !

```
>>> from datetime import date

>>> today=date(2011,10,11)
```

But how do I do this ?

```
>>> day =  '2011/10/11'

>>> today=date(day.split('/'))
```

note:

```
>>> day.split('/') 

['2011', '10', '11']
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638/how-to-split-a-string-into-two-integers-in-python) link.But i need integers for the **date()** not a list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`datetime.datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), which is designed specifically for parsing dates:

```
In [5]: datetime.datetime.strptime('2011/12/03', '%Y/%m/%d').date()
Out[5]: datetime.date(2011, 12, 3)
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
date(*map(int, day.split('/')))

>>> map(int, day.split('/'))
[2011, 10, 11]
>>> date(*map(int, day.split('/')))
datetime.date(2011, 10, 11)
```

Comment: apologies for posting a dup, beat me by seconds, no reloads. +1

Answer (score 2):

Python has a special syntax for passing a sequence as the arguments:

```
today=date(*day.split('/'))
```

But the parameters also have to be ints, so you can use:

```
today=date(*map(int,day.split('/')))
```

Comment: **passing a sequence as the arguments** That was what i wanted to know.Thanks.But aix has the more appropriate answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the list you get from day.split() and convert each entry to an int.

```
today = date([int(x) for x in day.split('/')])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> date( *(map(int,day.split('/'))))
datetime.date(2011, 10, 11)
```