# How to split list elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to read from file into a 2D list.
The file looks like:

> Jack 32
>   Perry 12
>   Tim 14

etc.

When I print the list it looks like:

```
['Jack 32', 'Perry 12', 'Tim 14']
```

But I need it to look like:

```
['Jack', '32', 'Perry', '12', 'Tim', '14']
```

So far my code looks like this:

```
with open('filelocation', 'r') as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]
    print(content)
```

Comment: Check this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a string into two integers in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638/how-to-split-a-string-into-two-integers-in-python)

Comment: your x.strip('\n') is splitting by lines, you need to split by lines or blank spaces

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just split the whole file on whitespace?

```
>>> with open('filelocation') as f:
        print(f.read().split())

['Jack', '32', 'Perry', '12', 'Tim', '14']
```

No point creating structure only to flatten it away.

Answer (score 1):

Split the string for each element in `['Jack 32', 'Perry 12', 'Tim 14']` using space as a separator (default).

Iterate through the resulting list to flatten it out.

```
mylist = ['Jack 32', 'Perry 12', 'Tim 14']
my_new_list = []
for l in mylist:
    my_new_list.extend(l.split())
```

Or, you could use a generator

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to read as a string and split on whitespace.

```
with open('filelocation') as f:
    split_up = f.read().split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
my_list = []
with open('your_file') as f:
    for x in f:
        my_list += x.strip().split()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you took the contents of the list you get back and split it on white space that will give you what you're looking for.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 0):

There might be a simple method than this

```
 In [46]: a=['Jack 32', 'Perry 12', 'Tim 14']

In [47]: b=[i.split() for i in a ]
In [49]: b
Out[49]: [['Jack', '32'], ['Perry', '12'], ['Tim', '14']]

In [50]: [item for sublist in b for item in sublist]
Out[50]: ['Jack', '32', 'Perry', '12', 'Tim', '14']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the elements with itertools.chain after splitting each line:

```
from itertools import chain
with open('filepath') as f:
    content = list(chain.from_iterable(x.split() for x in f))
    print(content)
['Jack', '32', 'Perry', '12', 'Tim', '14']
```

You don't need to call `.readlines`, you can iterate over the file object `f`. `line.strip("\n")` just strips the newlines, you don't actually split. If you call split on each line you will end up with a list of lists  like  `[['Jack', '32'], ['Perry', '12'], ['Tim', '14']]`, `chain.from_iterable` chains the elements from each sublist into a single list.

`.readlines` reads all the lines into memory at once which for a small file won't matter but if you have large files or restricted memory you should avoid calling `.read` or `.readlines`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not stream the file into a string with spaces between the new lines, then split by the space?

All you want to do is split by space anyway.

I know this isn't the "sexiest" answer, but probably the most straight forward for your use case.