# How do I pull a substring from a string in Python?

Tags: string, python-3.x, substring

Good evening. Today, I was writing a piece of code in Python. I have a string that is called date. It holds the following data:

```
date='05/04/2014'
```

So. I want to split this string into several substrings, each holding the day, month or year. These substrings will be called day, month and year, with the respective number in each string. How could I do this?

Also, I would like this method to work for any other date strings, such as:

```
02/07/2012
```

Comment: `d,m,y = date.split("/")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a string into two integers in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638/how-to-split-a-string-into-two-integers-in-python)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre excellent! You should post that as an answer so I could accept it.

Comment: Willem already did. You can accept his.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre oh I didn't notice k

Answer (score 2):

Simply use:

```
day,month,year = date.split('/')
```

Here you `.split(..)` the string on the slash (`/`) and you use *sequence unpacking* to store the first, second and third group in `day`, `month` and `year` respectively. Here `date` is the string that contains the date (`'05/04/2014'`) and `'/'` is the split pattern.

```
>>> day,month,year = date.split('/')
>>> day
'05'
>>> month
'04'
>>> year
'2014'
```

Note that `day`, `month` and `year` are **still strings** (not integers).

Comment: I assume that "/" is my string of the date?

Comment: @pagie_: no `date` is the string of your `date` in `date.split(..)`. `'/'` is the splitter.

Comment: oh i see. thanks ill accept when stackoverflow lets me