# Creating tuple from a text file

Tags: python

I want to create tuple like this:

```
(num_rows, num_columns, matrix)
```

example be:

```
   (3,5,[['o','x','o','x','o'], ['o','o','o','x','x'], ['o','o','o','o','o']])
```

Input from text file:

```
3 5
o x o x o
o o o x x
o o o o o
```

Some code I have tired so far:

```
  file_name = open('input_1.txt', 'r')
        inputs= []
        for line in file_name:
            input= ((line.split('\t')))
            inputs.append(input)
        file_name.close()

        return (tuple(inputs))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
def getTuple():
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
        result = []
        matrix = []
        result.extend(map(int, file.readline().split()))
        for line in file:
            matrix.append(line.split())
        result.append(matrix)
    return tuple(result)


print(getTuple())
```

Outputs:

```
(3, 5, [['o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']])
```

However, your code was returning:

```
(['3 5\n'], ['o x o x o\n'], ['o o o x x\n'], ['o o o o o'])
```

Let me walk you though the logic behind possible implementation (The points also point out the issues in your code):

1. You need to read/treat the first line differently than the rest of the lines in your file (it contains the number of rows and columns). You need to [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the first line using split() method (without any argument passed to it, see [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to know what difference it makes) and then use [map()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to convert each element in the first line to int. The object returned by map() (map object in Python 3.x) (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6429930/5735010) to learn more about map) is used to extend the list `result`.
2. Other lines needs to be split using `split()` and then appended to a list `matrix`. After the end of the for loop, we can append the matrix to the list `result`.
3. See [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/) to learn more about syntax used by me to manage the file resource (`with open('file.txt', 'r') as file`).

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2):

```
file_name = open('data.txt', 'r')


def generate_tuple(file_name):
    data = []
    for line in file_name.read().splitlines():
        data.append(list(line.replace(" ", "")))

    out = (len(data),len(data[0]), data)
    return out
```

**Output:**

```
(3, 5, [['o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']])
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is not the best solution but it give you the expected output:

Input:

```
3 5
o x o x o
o o o x x
o o o o o
```

I made some change to your code:

```
file_name = open('input_1.txt', 'r')
tmp= []
for line in file_name:
    input= ((line.split('\n'))) 
    #you split the line by \n so each line is a different list of 1 element in order 0
    input = input[0].split(" ")
    # you split each element of the list seeing that u have only one by space
    tmp.append(input)
file_name.close()


inputs = [tmp[0][0], tmp [0][1], tmp[1:]] 
#seeing that you want the first two values out of the sublist you rework it in the needed format
print inputs
```

This is the output:

```
['3', '5', [['o', 'x', 'o', 'x', 'o'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'x', 'x'], ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

*Sample Input Text:* "input_1.txt"

```
o x o x o x
o o o x x x
o o o o o x
o o o x x x
o o o o o x
o o o x x x
o o o o o o
o o o x x x
```

*Solution:*

```py
def create_matrix_tuple(file_name):
    """
    l. Loads the text file
    2. Initialises empty content of the file
    3. Get the length of rows and length of columns
    """
    # Reads in the data
    file_name = open("input_1.txt", "r")

    # initialises input content with empty list
    output = []

    # Loop over every line of the content
    line_text = file_name.read().splitlines()
    for line in line_text:
        output.append(
            list(
                line.replace(" ", "")
            )
        )        
    num_rows, num_cols = len(output), len(output[0])

    return (num_rows, num_cols, output)

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    desired_output = create_matrix_tuple(file_name)    
    print(desired_output)
```