# String with number on each line to list of floats

Tags: python

I am building a Python code that should read a text file using `askopenfile` in `tkinter` in Python. The text file is just a column of numbers:

```
300.0
250.0 
250.0
250.0
250.0 
270.61032473 
289.91197172 
290.23398559 
275.90792547
263.86956625 
264.8385967
```

My code is attached below:

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *
import numpy as np
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile 

root = Tk() 

t=12
p=np.empty(t)

def open_file(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('all files', '*.*')]) 
    if file is not None: 
        global x
        x = file.read() 
        print(x)
        global p
        global count

        #x=x.split('\n')

        #count=0
        #for row in x:

         #   i=float(row[0])#change from string to float type
          #  p[count]=i #updates x array
           # count +=1 # increment of 1 to get the number of total values

        #p=p.reshape(t,1)

        #print(p) 

        return x

#print(p)
btn = Button(root, text ='Open', command = lambda:open_file()) 
btn.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10) 

mainloop()
```

When I print x from the command window, the result is the following:

```
'300.0 \n300.0 \n250.0 \n250.0\n250.0\n250.0 \n270.61032473 \n289.91197172 \n290.23398559 \n275.90792547\n263.86956625 \n264.8385967'
```

Hence when I `print x[0]` for instance, the results is only: `3`.

I actually want `x[0]` to be `300.0`, `x[1]` to be `250.0`, etc.

In addition to that, I want to convert them to numerical numbers not strings.

Comment: Yes because the code attached is just a small part of a much larger code that has GUI (Tkinter) and Neural Networks my friend..

Comment: `import *` is generally bad practice. Why do you declare so many global variables, instead of returning the values?

Comment: Also, couldn't you simplify `command = lambda:open_file()` to `command=open_file`? Finally, from the code you commented out, I don't think you need to use NumPy here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string of space separated numbers into integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638/how-to-split-a-string-of-space-separated-numbers-into-integers)

Comment: This is a duplicate of the above ^ , the only difference is the character to split on, which is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To parse the string x

```
x = '300.0 \n300.0 \n250.0 \n250.0\n250.0\n250.0 \n270.61032473 \n289.91197172 \n290.23398559 \n275.90792547\n263.86956625 \n264.8385967'
```

into a list of numbers, you could do:

```
x_as_list_of_numbers = [float(xx.strip()) for xx in x.split('\n')]
```