# Is it possible to split a string in half at a specific point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, split, string-length

I need to split a string in half which I've already done with:

`firstpart, secondpart = string[:len(string)//2], string[len(string)//2:]`

I need it to split at a line break and I'm too new at coding to know how to approach this. Any tips would help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string of space separated numbers into integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638/how-to-split-a-string-of-space-separated-numbers-into-integers)

Comment: Which do you want, to split it in _half_, or to split at a line break?

Comment: In half at the nearest line break.

Comment: Give as an example of the input and output.

Comment: @BirdLeaf Please provide input example and explicitly show how you want to split it. A concrete example will help people to answer your question accurately.

Comment: I'm trying to split song lyrics so it would turn this:

Every day, the hours pass by
So quickly, yet I don't do a thing

I must be dumb
I've been feelin' numb
I can't explain, why nothing's gettin' done

Please don't write this off, like you did the last 12 years
I need a break, I need to breath
I bet I need a thousand things

So it here it goes, another chance
Giving up at last love's first glance of real life
You know that I don't handle pressure well

Everyone would like to think it's
Possible without having to think

In half to send it in two separate messages.

Comment: Formatting screwed up but genius page is https://genius.com/Ovens-dead-as-fuck-lyrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [splitlines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) method which will work perfectly in your case,

```
str1="hope\n this helps\n you"
print(str1.splitlines())
```

output:

```
['hope', ' this helps', ' you']
```

It returns a list of splitted string.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: you're welcome it has been my pleasure to help you out!

Comment: Comments attached to the question say that the requirement is to split "In half at the nearest line break." This splits into a list of as one element per line (three in this example).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the string has only one line break.

That would be:

```
firstpart, secondpart = string.split('\n')
```

Comment: My main issue is that there is multiple line breaks and I dont know how to distinguish which one to split at.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```py
mystring = """Mae hen wlad fy nhadau yn annwyl i mi,
Gwlad beirdd a chantorion, enwogion o fri;
Ei gwrol ryfelwyr, gwladgarwyr tra mad,
Dros ryddid collasant eu gwaed.

Gwlad!, GWLAD!, pleidiol wyf i'm gwlad.
Tra mor yn fur i'r bur hoff bau,
O bydded i'r hen iaith barhau.

Hen Gymru fynyddig, paradwys y bardd,
Pob dyffryn, pob clogwyn, i'm golwg sydd hardd;
Trwy deimlad gwladgarol, mor swynol yw si
Ei nentydd, afonydd, i fi.
"""

# get the half-way index
halfway = len(mystring) // 2

# get the indices of the nearest \n characters before and after the halfway
try:
    next_one = mystring.index("\n", halfway)
except ValueError:
    next_one = None

try:
    previous_one = mystring.rindex("\n", 0, halfway)
except ValueError:
    previous_one = None

# if no \n found at all, raise an error
if next_one == None and previous_one == None:
    raise ValueError

# or if a \n is only found on one side of halfway, use that one
elif next_one == None:
    pos = previous_one

elif previous_one == None:
    pos = next_one

# or if it is found on both sides of half-way, use whichever is nearer
elif next_one - halfway < halfway - previous_one:
    pos = next_one

else:
    pos = previous_one

# now actually split the string
part1 = mystring[:pos]
part2 = mystring[pos + 1:]

print("FIRST HALF:", part1)
print("==========")
print("SECOND HALF:", part2)
```

Gives:

```
FIRST HALF: Mae hen wlad fy nhadau yn annwyl i mi,
Gwlad beirdd a chantorion, enwogion o fri;
Ei gwrol ryfelwyr, gwladgarwyr tra mad,
Dros ryddid collasant eu gwaed.

Gwlad!, GWLAD!, pleidiol wyf i'm gwlad.
==========
SECOND HALF: Tra mor yn fur i'r bur hoff bau,
O bydded i'r hen iaith barhau.

Hen Gymru fynyddig, paradwys y bardd,
Pob dyffryn, pob clogwyn, i'm golwg sydd hardd;
Trwy deimlad gwladgarol, mor swynol yw si
Ei nentydd, afonydd, i fi.
```

Comment: previous_one is misspelled when you assign it to None.