# How can i convert string to int list with python?

Tags: python, list, converters

```
stringIds = "948274432, 948364892, 943224012"
```

I have such a string. How can I transfer the ids here into a list by converting them to int?

```
intList = []
for x in stringIds:
    intList.append(int(x))
```

I tried a code like this but the error I got `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ','`

Here is the sample list I want to get

```
intList = [948274432, 948364892, 943224012]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a string of space separated numbers into integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429638/how-to-split-a-string-of-space-separated-numbers-into-integers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) can split the string at the commas, then you can apply `int` to each element to get them as numbers.

```
intList = [int(x) for x in stringIds.split(', ')]
```

or, written out as a `for` loop like in your example,

```
intList = []
for x in stringIds.split(', '):
    intList.append(int(x))
```