# Converting item to a list

Tags: python, list, integer

I am new to using python. I have a list of integers that I want to convert into an actual list.  This is the result that I'm getting

```
>>>si(2358) 
(((2, 3), 5), 8)...
```

I want to be able to sort the result in ascending order so I think I'm going to have this in an actual list:

`[2,3,5,8]`

How can I go about doing this?
Code:

```
>>> def si(n):    
...     if (n)<10:
...         return n
...     else:
...         return si(lastdig(n, 10)), allbutlast(n)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - converting a string of numbers into a list of int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334374/python-converting-a-string-of-numbers-into-a-list-of-int)

Comment: it looks that you are creating tuples. show you code, it will be easier to give a hint.

Comment: probably using append, instead of extend.

Comment: The question is not clear, S. If you post your code, we'll be able to help better

Comment: @idjaw I followed that ink and it dosn't apply to my problem.

Comment: @LetzerWille I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @ergonaut expound please

Comment: It will really help if you show more code. We need to see what else you are doing.

Comment: post....your.....code

Comment: I'm with @idjaw.  Show us your hand, we can be your extra eyes.

Comment: I added it to the above... @idjaw

Comment: OK....what is lastdig doing and what is allbutlast doing? Also, you are returning this: `return si(lastdig(n, 10)), allbutlast(n)`. Your function will return what is called a tuple. Info: [Tuple](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm). Are you sure you want to be doing that?

Comment: @idjaw no I do not want to return a tuple I want to return a list. lastdig returns the lastdigit of the integer entered and allbutlast returns the remainding digits.  They were previousy created functions that calculate the mod and the quotient of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
n = 2358
l = [int(c) for c in str(n)]
```