# Nested list in pairs from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Input list example = `['listen, silent', 'dog, fog', 'colour, simple']`

how do I return a nested list from the example in pairs, to look like this:

```
[[word1,word2], [word3,word4]...etc]
```

please, thank you

I have tried list comprehension,

```
my_list1 = [i[1] for i in my_list]
 my_list2 = [i[0] for i in my_list]
```

but it took out only the first letter instead of word... hoping for it to look like;

```
[listen, silent],[dog, fog]...etc
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, @Alice? Please edit your question to detail your tries, otherwise, most probably your question will be closed

Comment: but you can try the split method to do so:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071396/split-by-comma-and-strip-whitespace-in-python

Comment: What is your expected output for your example `['listen, silent', 'dog, fog', 'colour, simple']`? `[['listen, silent'], ['dog, fog'], ['colour, simple']]`?

Comment: @quant yes exactly that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split each word in the list using `,` as a separator:

```
l = ['listen, silent', 'dog, fog', 'colour, simple']

l = [elem.split(', ') for elem in l]
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[['listen', 'silent'], ['dog', 'fog'], ['colour', 'simple']]
```

Comment: thank you so very much! Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome. Is this what you were asking for? Because in your question it is kind of unclear whether you want to split each string and get the two words, or place each string in a list like this: `[['listen, silent'],['dog, fog'], ['colour, simple']]`. Notice the difference between these two.

Comment: ah, my next step is to use a sorted function in order to check if the list of words are anagrams or not (so read_anagram: if (sorted(s1)==sorted(s2)) )- therefore the function needs to recognise the pairs into 2 strings.. so perhaps for this, your first output would work better?

Comment: Well, if this is the case, yes, the first output will work better.

Comment: Perfect - thank you v much :)