# Skipping split character

Tags: python

I have string for example

```
subject = '=?UTF-8?Q?=C5=A0irvint=C5=B3_PSPC_ir_TENESYS_3CX_RESTful_API?='
```

I want to split it by `'?='` and it working ok if there is only 1 `'?='` my string, but when I have more than 1 I'm getting problems. 
I know that I can split my string skipping that ?= that is going after "`=?UTF-8?Q"`

this is my code

```
 for split_begin in subject.split('=?'):
                for split_end in split_begin[:2].split('?='):
                    if 'UTF-8' in split_end:
                        special_word = '=?' + split_end + '?='
                        word_list.append(special_word)
```

UPDATE.

when string is '=?UTF-8?Q?=C5=A0irvint=C5=B3_PSPC_ir_TENESYS_3CX_RESTful_API?='

```
split end = 'UTF-8?Q'
```

this is bad output.

when string is `subject = '=?UTF-8?Q?D=C4=97l_greito_va=C5=BEiavimo?='

```
split end = 'UTF-8?Q?D=C4=97l_greito_va=C5=BEiavimo'
```

this is good output.

different in the string that second string has only 1 `?=` in it

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Using complete sentences would help us understand what you are trying to do. Show example/desired output.

Comment: "I'm getting problems", what problems exactly? The string would still split but what is your expected vs actual output?

Comment: list comprehension is a way to achieve this. I think.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071396/split-by-comma-and-strip-whitespace-in-python

Comment: Perhaps you really meant `word_list = [s + '?=' for s in subject.split('?=') if 'UTF-8' in s]`

Comment: updated my question

Comment: See the duplicate I tagged - there are tools for decoding this data, you don't need to do it manually

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to accomplish, but !

`subject.split('?=')` will give you the output you want - meaning it will split your string according to the `seperator` you gave it.

i think that your problem occur since you accidentally wrote :

`subject.split('=?')` instead of `subject.split('?=')`

hope it helps.