# How to convert a doube quoted string to single quotes for each indivdial value in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a string

S= "SD,HG,FG,LM"

I would like to convert this to a single quotes for each element?

S = 'SD','HG','FG','LM'

I need this way because i get some configurations from a json which is in double quotes and I would like to format it in the required manner to pass it onto a where clause in a select query in sql

"""SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ({X});""" .format(X = S)

Comment: Why does it matter if they are single or double quotes?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split by comma and strip whitespace in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071396/split-by-comma-and-strip-whitespace-in-python)

Comment: your question is not about quoting really. mind making proper post?

Comment: In python single and double quotes are exactly the same.

Comment: try this S.split(', ')

Comment: Where is your proposed code to solve the issue?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

try inbuilt function split() to get desired output.

```
s= S.split(',')
print(s)
```